# FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever from External Storage? Android Studio/Kotlin

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg, mediametadataretriever

So I'm making my first Android app and I'm trying to get it to allow the user to pick a video from their gallery before seeing the video and the video's current details in the next activity.
My problem is that when I use FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever and pass it the video's filepath, I receive the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFFF`.
I've heard through the grapevine that this means my filepath is invalid. When I `Log.d` the filepath, I get `content://media/external/file/3565`, which to me looks like a proper filepath!
I hope somebody can help me figure this out.

Here is my activity class for context:

```
class NewProject : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_project)

        val videoPath = intent.getStringExtra("video")
        initVideo(videoPath)

        backButtonText.setOnClickListener{ goBack() }
    }

    private fun goBack() {
        val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun initVideo(videoPath:String) {
        newProjVideoView.setVideoPath(videoPath)
        newProjVideoView.start()
        newProjVideoView.setOnCompletionListener {
            newProjVideoView.pause()
        }
        getVideoMetadata(videoPath)
    }

    private fun getVideoMetadata(videoPath: String) {
        try {
            e("videoPath", videoPath)
            val receiver = FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever()
            receiver.setDataSource(videoPath)

        } catch (e:IOException) {
            e("retrieve1","There was an issue", e)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also happy to hear any constructive feedback on my code!
Please, thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

So, I think my issue stemmed from trying to pass the video through an intent and then running the MetadataRetriever. I solved it by getting all the info in the previous activity before passing each value as an extra to be used on the next screen.